# What is the noun of `save`?

Tags: nouns

I'm a software developer but not a native english speaker. So I stuck in finding a correct noun.

I'm implementing some events called in several states of the application.

E. g. the deletion.

```
deleting:          called while the deletion of data has been started
deletionSucceeded: called if the data deletion succeeded
deletionFailed:    called if the data deletion failed
```

According to these terms I'm looking for the equivalents of `save`, especially the noun of save.

```
saving
?-Succeeded
?-Failed
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the naming of software artifacts is specifically off topic for this site.

Comment: The noun forum of *save* is *save*.

Comment: @robusto The naming of software artifacts is just my use case scenario. But in fact this question is about `the noun of save` which isn't off topic. I found an example sentence: "The goalie guarded the net well and made a crucial save."

Comment: @codekandis just like you I'm a programmer but not a native English speaker. The most common choice I see is *"save successful"* (not *"save succeeded"*) and *"save failed"*.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado In your case it's the same noun. But the opposite of `successful` is `unsuccessful`, not `failed`.

Comment: @codekandis sorry, I was not clear: what I meant is that among all softwares I've seen so far in my life the most common choices are *"save successful"* and *"save failed"*. Why these programmers (probably English native speakers) chose *failed* instead of *unsuccessful* is something I don't know.

Comment: @codekandis There are a couple of reasons for using "failed". The first is that it means "failed to complete" which is slightly more specific than "unsuccessful" and the other, probably more significant, reason is that it cannot be confused with "successful" at a quick glance at a message or in a long activity log.

Comment: I tend to use succeeded and failed while they're both the same tense and they're opposites.